# Docker compose up fails with `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/rails (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rails:4.2.4
MAINTAINER Brena Monteiro <me@monteirobrena.com>
RUN mkdir -p ~/myapp
COPY . ~/myapp
COPY Gemfile ~/myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile ~/myapp/Gemfile.lock
WORKDIR ~/myapp
RUN bundle install
CMD rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

And my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  ports:
    - '3000:8080'
  volumes:
    - .:/Users/monteirobrena/myapp
```

If I run `docker run` the Docker is start correctly:

```
docker run -v ./:/Users/monteirobrena/docker/myapp -p 3000:8080 myapp
```

But when I run `docker-compose up` I receive this error:

```
➜  app git:(add-docker) ✗ docker-compose up         
myRecreating app_web_1
myAttaching to app_web_1
web_1 | /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:78:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/rails (LoadError)
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:78:in `try_require'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:16:in `get'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:290:in `server'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:125:in `print_boot_information'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
web_1 |   from /usr/src/app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
web_1 |   from /usr/src/app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.4/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
web_1 |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
web_1 |   from /usr/src/app/bin/spring:13:in `require'
web_1 |   from /usr/src/app/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
web_1 |   from bin/rails:3:in `load'
web_1 |   from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
web_1 | Exiting
myapp_web_1 exited with code
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it working without docker?

Comment: Yes, works fine without Docker and with `docker run`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bundle exec` to start the rails server, like this:

```
 web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  ports:
    - '3000:8080'
  volumes:
    - .:/Users/monteirobrena/myapp
```

Comment: What about this line `COPY Gemfile ~/myapp/Gemfile.lock` shouldn't that be `COPY Gemfile.lock ~/myapp/Gemfile.lock` ?

Comment: Can you remove the last line of your Docker file `CMD rails s -b 0.0.0.0` and try running docker-compose again?

Comment: When I change to `bundle exec rails s` I receive this error ` `require': cannot load such file`.

Comment: Same without `CMD` line :(

Comment: Did you run `docker-compose build` before `docker-compose up` ?

Comment: I copy/paste your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose-yml` files on an existing project. I was able to `build` and `up`, can you add your `Gemfile` to your question?

Comment: Now it's working. I delete my files and recreate them. Thank you.